# XSLT : access grandchildren of given node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml,

```
<doc>
    <table type="Horizontal lines" width="100%">
             <group cols="5">
                <colspec colname="1" colwidth="58%"/>
                <colspec colname="2" colwidth="32%"/>

                <thead>
                   <row>
                      <entry namest="1" align="center">
                         <p type="Table head">Testing Table</p>
                      </entry>
                      <entry namest="2" align="center">
                         <p type="Table head">Testing Head</p>
                      </entry>
                   </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <row>
                      <entry namest="1" align="left">
                         <p type="Table text">Mobile OS</p>
                      </entry>
                      <entry namest="2" align="left">
                         <p type="Table text">Android</p>
                      </entry>
                   </row>
                   <row>
                      <entry namest="4" align="left">
                         <p type="Table text">
                             <link type="Hyperlink">www.facebook.com</link>  
                         </p>
                         <p type="Table text"/>
                      </entry>
                      <entry namest="4" align="left">
                         <p type="Table text">
                             <link type="Hyperlink">www.skynews.com</link>  
                         </p>
                         <p type="Table text"/>
                      </entry>
                   </row>
            </tbody>
      </group>
    </table>
    <para>
      <entry namest="4" align="left">
         <p type="Table text">
            <link type="Hyperlink">www.devandroid.com</link>  
         </p>
           <p type="Table text">
            <link type="Hyperlink">www.google.com</link>  
         </p>
         <p type="Table text"/>
      </entry>
    </para>
<doc>
```

as you can see there are some `<link>` nodes in the document placed grandchildren of `<table>` node and and some `<link>` nodes are out of the `<table>` nodes (no relationship with `<table>` node. 
what I need to do is simply convert `<link>` nodes text (which are places as grandchildren's of `<table>` nodes) in to uppercase letter.
(in this example, only `<link type="Hyperlink">www.facebook.com</link> and <link type="Hyperlink">www.skynews.com</link>` should be capitalized.)

So, how can I only select `<link>` nodes which are only within the `<table>` node ?

I tried some codes as follows,but it did not give the result.

```
<xsl:template match="table::link">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
             more codes...
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

any suggestions how can I access grandchildren's of table node ??

Comment: use the xpath `table//link`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following match pattern for links in a table (the default template rule for links will have a lower priority):

```
<xsl:template match="link[ancestor::table]">
   ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```